# Obfuscate generated fat jar with gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin, proguard

I'm creating a desktop application with Kotlin and I'm trying to obfuscate the final output

I work on an application using JavaFx and Kotlin. I work with Gradle as a build tool and I'm searching how to obfuscate my jar in order to avoid reverse-enginneering on the jar. The generated jar is a fat jar (all library are inside the jar). I already tried using proguard in my gradle.build but everytime I run my build I get lot of "can't find referenced class" with native java library class such as Object, String, and so on.

Here is my current proguard task:

```
def jarNameWithoutExtension = jar.archiveName.with { 
it.take(it.lastIndexOf(".")) }
def obfuscatedJarName = "${jarNameWithoutExtension}-release.jar"
def jarFileLocation = jar.archivePath.parent
def obfuscatedFilePath = Paths.get(jarFileLocation, obfuscatedJarName)

task obfuscate(type: ProGuardTask) {
    configuration 'proguard.txt'

    injars jar.archivePath
    outjars obfuscatedFilePath.toString()
    libraryjars files(configurations.compile.collect())
    libraryjars "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/lib/rt.jar"
    doLast {
        jar.archivePath.renameTo(Paths.get(jarFileLocation, "$jarNameWithoutExtension-original.jar").toFile())
        obfuscatedFilePath.toFile().renameTo(jar.archivePath)
    }
}

jar.finalizedBy(project.tasks.obfuscate)
```

The proguard.txt file is currently empty
An error example is "Warning: javafx.animation.Animation: can't find superclass or interface java.lang.Object"

I expect to have an obfuscated jar file produced when building my project, but all I've got is compilation error

I hope that somebody can help me with my problem

Answer (score 0):

JShrinker is a jar obfuscation tool that provides a graphical user interface. If you're not limited to Pro Guard, it may solve your issue. It's very user friendly and saves you all of the configuration and head scratching that is nearly unavoidable with other programs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after using JShrinker my Jar had a Exception when running:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
And I don't know how to fix it

Comment: What JDK did you use? Also, which IDE do you use? Keep in mind that JavaFX is no longer included in the JDK after JDK8. You should check the OpenJFX website for build instructions if you’re using 8+.

Comment: I use the last JDK (11), OpenJFX are in my dependencies and in my fat jar (otherwise I shouldn't have been able to build the project and test it before). For the IDE I use IntelliJ but it's not important because I build on a terminal using gradle commands, and I need to keep it this way

Comment: I wanted also to be clearer I need my jar to be obfuscated during the build with gradle. Like so it could prevent the release of a non obfuscate build because I forgot to run the obfuscator on it